# Diference beetwen detect{} and select{}[0]

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm consider about diference beetwen these methods in ruby. I know, `select` returns an array of elements, and `detect` return only one and first consisten element. But is there any diference if i type `array.select{ condition }[0]`? It will return first unit like `detect`. 
For example:

```
a = [2,3,4,5]
a.detect{|k| k.even? }
# => 2
a.select{|k| k.even? }[0]
# => 2
```

Anyone can explain me other distinctions beetwen these methods and give me some examples when `detect` will be better than `select`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you only need to retrieve one item, `detect` is preferable because it will stop iterating over the array when it finds the first occurrence matching the condition. Because `select` retrieves all occurrences that match the condition, it has to iterate over the entire list. In the worst case (where an item matching the condition is not in the list) these are equivalent, but if the item you are looking for is early in the list `detect` will be more performant.

Comment: Also `a.detect {|k| p k; k.even? }` will have different output to `a.select {|k| p k; k.even? }[0]`

Answer (score 4):

I would post here an example, that IMHO clarifies everything:

```
(1..Float::INFINITY).detect &:odd?
#⇒ 1
(1..Float::INFINITY).select(&:odd?).first
#⇒ :(
```

Comment: `(1..Float::INFINITY).lazy.select(&:odd?).first` ;-)

Comment: @Stefan Yet another implementation of `detect` in pure ruby? :)

Answer (score 1):

The difference is `detect` will return the first value that the block evaluates to true, in this case, it is the number `2`. It is faster if you just want one value from the array, because it will not evaluate the rest of the array after finding one value that returns `true`.

`select` will return every element that returns `true` based on the block, so it will return `[2,4]`. `select` will evaluate the block for every element, so it is slower than `detect`.

Based on what you did in your example, where you only select the first element that `select` returned, it is best that you use `detect` instead.

A good illustration of this will be, say you have an array of 10 million items, which random numbers from 0 to 1 million.

```
arr = Array.new(1_000_000) { rand(1_000_000) }
```

If you just want to return the first even number, using `detect` in this value will be considerably faster than `select`. Here are the benchmark measurements for `detect` and `select`.

```
detect:  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000010)
select:  0.740000   0.010000   0.750000 (  0.753949)
```

Comment: An even better illustration is that `select` and `detect` are methods of `Enumerable`, and `Enumerable`s are not only allowed to be very large (like your example), but even infinite!